# Функций которая по идентификатору категории возвращает название категории

Tags: php

Дбрый день. Нужно реализовать функцию, которая по идентификатору категории возвращает название категории.(Передаю 'id' и нужео что бы вывело значение ключа 'title' , котоырй находится в том же массиве).
При реализации возникают трудности, в голове вроде бы есть алгоритм ,но не до конца могу его воплотить в коде:

```
        <?php
    
    $categories = [
        "id" => 1,
        "title" => "Компьютеры",
        "children" => [
            ["id" => 2, "title" => "Стационарные"],
            ["id" => 3, "title" => "Моноблоки"],
            ["id" => 4, "title" => "Ноутбуки"]
        ]
    ];
    
    function searchCategories($categories, $id) // Передается массив и id требуемой категории
{
    foreach ($categories as $key => $item) {
        if ($item == $id) {
            echo "По вашему идентификатору найдена категория" . ' ';
        } elseif (is_array($item)) {
            searchCategories($item, $id);
        }
    }
}


searchCategories($categories, 3);
```

Comment: До меня ещё дошло что число многомерных массивов должно быть не ограниченно следственно что бы функция вызывала сама себя что бы "копать" глубже...

Comment: совершенно верно, вызывала сама себя. примеров в интернете примерно миллион

Comment: @Ипатьев не доходит всё же как подогнать рекурсию под моё условие, уже только как и не пробовал... :с. Что то примерное получается если в if пишу это  if (is_array($item) and $item == $id){
            searchCategories($item, $id);

Comment: а где проверка, я извиняюсь, на соответствие $id?

Comment: у вас на верхнем уровне категорий только один элемент всегда? или их может быть потенцаильно несколько? а то поулчается, что сверху "объект" а внутри массивы "объектов"  и `is_array` вернет вам всегда true

Comment: @teran. Нет, это только пример. В массиве может быть неограниченное число многомерных масивов, в том числе и на самом верхнем(первом) уровне

Comment: @teran да он is_array применяет механически. просто потому что в примере из интернета так было. То есть спрашивать его "почему" - бесполезно. Он не знает :)

Comment: @Ипатьев ну так думаю что бы проверить значение ключа на данной итерации и если он является массивом то бишь тру начинается рекурсия функции, которая уже работает в двумерном массиве и т.д

Answer (score 0):

1. Этот масив скоре всего вы будете брать с бд так что можна использоть mysql запрос что бы получить нужную категорию.
2. Немного не понял смысла поиска в одномерном масиве но если все верно то решение следуйщее:

   ```
    <?php
   ```

function searchCategories($categories, $id, $b = false)
{

```
if (isset($categories['id']) && $categories['id'] == $id) {
    echo $categories['title'];
}

if (isset($categories['children'])) {
    searchCategories($categories['children'], $id);
}

if (is_array($categories) && !isset($categories['id'])) {
    foreach($categories as $key => $value)
    {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            searchCategories($value, $id, $key == 1);
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
$categories = [
    "id" => 1,
    "title" => "Компьютеры",
    "children" => [
        ["id" => 2, "title" => "Стационарные"],
        ["id" => 3, "title" => "Моноблоки"],
        ["id" => 4, "title" => "Ноутбуки"]
    ]
];
```

searchCategories($categories, 3);

Comment: Спасибо за принятие участия. Параллельно пока вы это писали, решил самостоятельно. Данная функция не подразумевает продакшена и какого то в будующем применения вместе с БД. Просто контректное задание :)

Answer (score 0):

Помощи как таковой не даждался, додумался сам:

```
    <?php

$categories = [
    "id" => 1,
    "title" => "Компьютеры",
    "children" => [
        ["id" => 2, "title" => "Стационарные"],
        ["id" => 3, "title" => "Моноблоки"],
        ["id" => 4, "title" => "Ноутбуки"]
    ]
];

function searchCategories($categories, $id) // Передается массив и id требуемой категории
{
    foreach ($categories as $key => $item) {
        if ($item == $id) {
            echo "По вашему идентификатору найдена категория" . ' ' . $categories['title'];
        } elseif (is_array($item)) {
            searchCategories($item, $id);
        }
    }
}

searchCategories($categories, 3);
```